# CSS root variables are not changing on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I tried to figure out why the `:root` variables are not changing but failed to do that. Can someone help me.

Actually I am trying to create a tilting card that tilts on mouse hover but for some reason it is not working as expected.

You can also check it on codepen. Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/wasifnaeem/pen/abGLzJg?editors=1100)

```css
:root {
  --width: 420px;
  --height: 560px;
  
  --perspective: 1000px;
  --rotateX: 0deg;
  --rotateY: 0deg;
}

.card {
  position: relative;

  height: var(--height);
  width: var(--width);

  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  margin: auto;
  
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transform: perspective(var(--perspective)) rotateX(var(--rotateX)) rotateY(var(--rotateY));
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.mouse-tracker {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mouse-tracker > div {
  outline: 1px solid blue;

  width: calc(100% / 4);
  height: calc(100% / 4);
}

.mouse-tracker > div:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.mouse-tracker {
  --rotateX: 15deg;
  --rotateY: -15deg;
}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(1):hover {
  --rotateX: 15deg;
  --rotateY: -15deg;
  background-color: red;
}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(2):hover {
  --rotateX: 15deg;
  --rotateY: -15deg;
  background-color: red;
}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(3) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(4) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(5) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(6) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(7) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(8) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(9) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(10) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(11) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(12) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(13) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(14) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(15) {

}

.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(16) {

}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h1>Tilting Card</h1>
  <p>Hover to see effect!</p>

  <div class="mouse-tracker">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on the pen you linked I can see the whole `.card` tilt when hovering the first block, just like the rule in line 68 of the pen `.card:has(.mouse-tracker > div:nth-child(1):hover)` , the variables are being updated to the specified `15deg`, are you expecting that a hover on one of the `div`'s inside the `.card` should tilt the `.card` or just the `div` that was hovered

Comment: @Juan As per your comment, I tested it out on `chrome`, it worked. I think `:has()` is for now supported by `chrome`. I was testing it on `opera`.